# MongoDB Collection as data source for cs.js in Meteor app

Tags: mongodb, d3.js, meteor, c3

As the title says I'm using [c3.js](https://atmospherejs.com/peernohell/c3) to plot charts in a Meteor app. All the examples, however, statically set the variables for the data source.

I can't find the correct way to use `c3` with Mongo. Say I have a simple template like below

```
<template name="model1">
    <div class="chart"></div>
</template>
```

and then the chart code as follows

```
Template.model1.rendered = function () {
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: this.find('.chart'),
        data: {
            json: [
                {name: 'www.site1.com', upload: 100
                    , download: 200, total: 400}
            ],
            keys: {
                value: ['upload', 'download']
            }
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                // type: 'category'
            }
        }
    });
};
```

how can I populate that `json` field with the result of querying Mongo, something like `Models.find({"model" : "model1"},{"actual" : 1, "_id": 0})`.

Running the equivalent from the Mongo shell `db.models.find({"model" : "model1"},{"actual" : 1, "_id": 0})` returns `{"actual" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }`

I just can't figure out how to approach this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define [`Meteor.methods`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) and [`Meteor.call`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call) to retrieve data and populate it into d3.

methods.js

```
Meteor.methods({

  data: function(){

    check(arguments, [Match.Any]);

    return Models.find({"model" : "model1"},{"actual" : 1, "_id": 0}).fetch();

  }

});
```

template.html

```
Template.model1.onRendered(function () {

  var self = this;

  Meteor.call('data', function (error, result) {

    var chart = c3.generate({
      bindto: self.find('.chart'),
      data: {
        json: result,
        keys: {
          value: ['upload', 'download']
        }
      },
      axis: {
        x: {
          // type: 'category'
        }
      }
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: That looks to be what I'm looking for, but the chart is not rendering when it's within `Meteor.call` for some reason. Any idea why?